# Bracket Error in New User Sequence

Tags: java, sql

I Am currently working on a small project for myself which allows me to create new user to a database. Everything was going well until I noticed that one of my brackets on the code is displaying an error. Which is strange due to I checked I closed all of my brackets. If someone could see the missing bracket or help me fix the current ones it would be very useful.

```
    JButton NewUserBtn = new JButton("Create New User");
    NewUserBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String Username = userText.getText();
            String Password = passText.getText();
            String Email = emailText.getText();
            String cid = cidText.getText();
            try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );      
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `user_name`, `user_email` FROM `table_1` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `user_email` = ?");
                pst.setString(1, Username);
                pst.setString(2, Password);
                ResultSet Result = pst.executeQuery();
                if (Result.next()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Account with Infomation already exists.");
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_1 (user_name, user_pass, user_email, cid)"
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

                        pst2.setString(1, Username); //Check Username does not exist!
                        pst2.setString(2, Password);
                        pst2.setString(3, Email); //Check Email is not already used!
                        pst2.setString(4, cid); //Need to add verification that CID is not in use!

                        pst2.execute(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The Bracket is the second to last one. Is says I should add finally but I do not understand why? Thanks for anyone who can solve this problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to only have one try statement. The code below should be working fine.

```
 try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );      
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `user_name`, `user_email` FROM `table_1` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `user_email` = ?");
                pst.setString(1, Username);
                pst.setString(2, Password);
                ResultSet Result = pst.executeQuery();
                if (Result.next()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Account with Infomation already exists.");
                } // if
                else {
                        PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_1 (user_name, user_pass, user_email, cid)"
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

                        pst2.setString(1, Username); //Check Username does not exist!
                        pst2.setString(2, Password);
                        pst2.setString(3, Email); //Check Email is not already used!
                        pst2.setString(4, cid); //Need to add verification that CID is not in use!

                        pst2.execute();
                    } // else
                   } // try
                    catch (Exception e3) {
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                   } // catch
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me. I'm quite new to all of this Java SQL coding so its going to take awhile to getting used to it. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelQuinn I'm glad I could help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You dont `catch` or `finally` your first `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `try-catch` combination to inner `try` statement just above `PreparedStatement`, but outer `try` statement is missing `catch` or `finally`. See my comments below:

```
JButton NewUserBtn = new JButton("Create New User");
NewUserBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String Username = userText.getText();
        String Password = passText.getText();
        String Email = emailText.getText();
        String cid = cidText.getText();
        try { //But it doesn't have either catch or finally
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Host, Name, Pass );      
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `user_name`, `user_email` FROM `table_1` WHERE `user_name` = ? AND `user_email` = ?");
            pst.setString(1, Username);
            pst.setString(2, Password);
            ResultSet Result = pst.executeQuery();
            if (Result.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Account with Infomation already exists.");
            }
            else {
                try { //You have catch for this
                    PreparedStatement pst2 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table_1 (user_name, user_pass, user_email, cid)"
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

                    pst2.setString(1, Username); //Check Username does not exist!
                    pst2.setString(2, Password);
                    pst2.setString(3, Email); //Check Email is not already used!
                    pst2.setString(4, cid); //Need to add verification that CID is not in use!

                    pst2.execute(); 
                } 
                catch (Exception e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```